# is it possible to pass a multidimensional array via declaring it in a function? better just to declare it global?

Tags: php, function, arrays, foreach

good afternoon,

I've been trying to figure out build an array for use in multiple functions, inside `functions.php`. it appears that i need to create the array in its own function, and then refer to it inside the other functions. but then things get confusing for me.

I'm not looking to manipulate the data in these other functions referencing it, they just need access to the variables.

looking for something along the lines of :

```
function test($sample_array) 
    {
        return array 
            (    array('1','red'),
                 array('2','blue'),
                 array('3','green'),
                 array('4','yellow')  );
    } //close $sample_array

function sample_function( array test($sample_array) ) 
{  // blah blah function code

    foreach test($sample_array as $value) 
    {
        echo "color ". $value[2] ."<br>;"
        echo "number ". $value[1] ."<br>;"
    } //close foreach test

} //close sample_function

function other_example_function( array test($sample_array) ) 
{  // blah blah function code

    foreach test($sample_array as $value) 
    {
        echo "number". $value[1] ."<br>;"
        echo "color ". $value[2] ."<br>;"
    } //close foreach test

} //close other_example_function
```

but i can't find any examples even close to that structure. am i going about this incorrectly? or do i misunderstand how to share access to an `array`?

thanks!

Comment: Instead of `function sample_function( array test($sample_array) ) 
{ ` you have to do `function sample_function( $sample_array) 
{  $result = test($sample_array); // and then your for-each loop` and so on for other functions

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, @Anant ! -- please clarify what the purpose of the **$result** variable is? is that making a "local" version of the array to be used within the function, so i would use `foreach ($result as $value)` ?

Comment: outstanding link for the demonstration. thank you so much :)

Comment: follow up question : the two lines `sample_function($sample_array);` and `other_example_function($sample_array);` at the end. since they are outside the two sample functions using the array i'm not sure what they are doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code need lot of changes (all are done and specified also):-

```
<?php

function test() // since you are returning a newly created array so need of passing any array 
    {
        return array (array('1','red'),array('2','blue'),array('3','green'),array('4','yellow') );
    }

function sample_function()  // you have to call another function inside the function not in passed parameter
{ 
    $result = test($sample_array); // since function test() returns an array so you have to save that array into a variable and then you have to use it in foreach loop
    foreach ( $result as $value)  // use variable here not the function itself
    {
        echo "color ". $value[1] ."<br>"; // ; must be outside
        echo "number ". $value[0] ."<br>";// ; must be outside
    } 

}

function other_example_function()  // you have to call a function inside any function not in passed parameter
{ 

    $result = test($sample_array); // since function test() returns an array so you have to save that array into a variable and then you have to use it in foreach loop
    foreach ( $result as $value)  // use variable here not the function itself
    {
        echo "number ". $value[0] ."<br>";// ; must be outside
        echo "color ". $value[1] ."<br>"; // ; must be outside
    } 

}

// now call the function

sample_function();
other_example_function();
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/601096

The other solution (which i gave first) is here:-

https://eval.in/601102

Answer (score 2):

thanks everyone for your help :)

for anyone visiting this thread in the future, my objective was to pass a multidimensional array to several functions, for use in building an Admin Metabox.

since i find practical examples far more useful than code snippits, i'll include the complete code from `functions.php` below.

i have verified the code to create the Admin Metabox, save meta data, and delete old meta data when entries are cleared. the meta data properly loads on my development install of WP.

```
//
// RECIPE METABOX
//

// call the add_meta_box function
    function add_embed_recipe_meta_box() {
        add_meta_box( 'embed_recipe_meta_box',       // $id
                      'Recipe Post meta box',        // $title
                      'show_embed_recipe_meta_box',  // $callback
                      'post',                        // $page
                      'normal',                      // $context
                      'high' ); }

    add_action( "add_meta_boxes", "add_embed_recipe_meta_box" );

// build array for use in metabox
    function recipe($recipe_array) {
    return array 
        (    
        array('1','recipe_embed1','servings'), 
        array('2','recipe_embed2','prep time'), 
        array('3','recipe_embed3','cook time'), 
        array('4','recipe_embed4','ingredients'), 
        array('5','recipe_embed5','spices'),
        array('6','recipe_embed6','special tools') 
        );
    } // close function recipe

// add the admin metabox
    function show_embed_recipe_meta_box( $post,$recipe_array ) 
    {
       $result =  recipe($recipe_array);
       foreach ( $result as $value) 
       { ${'recipe_meta'.$value[0]} = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key=$value[1], true ); }

        wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), "recipe-meta-box-nonce" );

        //table content here
        echo "<table>";
        foreach ( $result as $value) 
            {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> <div class=\"meta-title\"> <label for=\"recipe_embed". $value[0]. "\">". $value[2] .".</label></div></td>";
            echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" size=\"60\" name=\"recipe_embed". $value[0]. "\" id=\"recipe_embed". $value[0]. "\" value=\"". ${'recipe_meta'.$value[0]} ."\"></td>";      
            echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";    
    } //closing show_embed_recipe_meta_box

// check and save the metabox data
    function save_recipe_embed( $post_id, $post, $update, $recipe_array ) 
    {
        // checking here
        if ( ! isset( $_POST[ "recipe-meta-box-nonce" ] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ "recipe-meta-box-nonce" ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) 
        { return $post_id; }

        if ( ! current_user_can( "edit_post", $post_id ) ) { return $post_id;}

        if ( defined( "DOING_AUTOSAVE" ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) { return $post_id; }

        $slug = "post";
        if ( $slug != $post->post_type ) { return $post_id; }

        // saving here  
        $result =  recipe($recipe_array);
        foreach ( $result as $value) 
            { 
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $key=$value[1], true);       
            $new = $_POST[$value[1]];
                if ($new && $new != $old) {
                    update_post_meta($post_id, $key=$value[1], $new);
                } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
                    delete_post_meta($post_id, $key=$value[1], $old);
                } 
             } // close foreach recipe_array
    } // close save_recipe_embed
    add_action( "save_post", "save_recipe_embed", 10, 3 );
```

passing the array let me eliminate about half of my original code!

i could make use of `foreach` to register the meta fields, display the Admin Metabox, and to save the meta fields. previously every meta field's creation/display/saving had to be individually coded.

thanks again for the help.

hopefully this is useful for someone else as well, since i was unable to find similar use of passing arrays in a syntax i could understand.

Answer (score 1):

**@Anant's brilliant answer**. but i cannot "accept" their answer since it was only entered as a comment, so i am redisplaying it here so i can mark my question answered.

```
<?php
$sample_array = array();
function test($sample_array) 
    {
        return array 
            (    array('1','red'),
                 array('2','blue'),
                 array('3','green'),
                 array('4','yellow')  );
    } 
function sample_function( $sample_array) 
{
    $result =  test($sample_array);
    foreach ( $result as $value) 
    {
        echo "color ". $value[0]."<br>";
        echo "number ".$value[1]."<br>";
    }

} 

function other_example_function( $sample_array ) 
{ 
     $result =  test($sample_array);
    foreach ( $result as $key=> $value) 
    {
        echo "number ".$value[1]."<br>";
        echo "color ". $value[0]."<br>";
    } 
}
sample_function($sample_array);
other_example_function($sample_array);
```

Comment: @ijason You need to wait 48 hours before accepting a self-answer; the idea is it gives others time to respond. But there's another answer here you can accept now!

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of problems with your code

```
function test($sample_array) ...
```

First off this function doesn't need the `$sample_array` parameter. The function does not use the parameter, so just remove it.

```
// "nullary" functions do not have any parameters
function test() {
  return array (
    array('1','red'),
    array('2','blue'),
    array('3','green'),
    array('4','yellow')
  );
}
```

Then you have these. What the heck are these? This is totally invalid PHP so I don't know why you're even asking about it, to be honest. If you would've fixed the syntax errors first, you might've arrived at your answer on your own.

```
// SYNTAX ERROR
function sample_function( array test($sample_array) ) ...
// and
function other_example_function( array test($sample_array) )  ...
```

These should just be functions that take an array

```
// correct function signature
function sample_function(array $arr) { ...
// and
function other_example_function(array $arr) { ...
```

The `array` type-hinting isn't even necessary if you don't want it. I personally like the type hinting, but it seems like you don't know much PHP so I'll show you that this is equally valid:

```
// also correct function signature
function sample_function($arr) { ...
// and
function other_example_function($arr) { ...
```

Now for working with the nested array... First, don't forget that arrays start with a `0` index. The first value is `$arr[0]` and the second value is `$arr[1]`, the third value is `$arr[2]`, etc. Second you have syntax errors with your echo statements

```
// SYNTAX ERRROR
echo "color ". $value[2] ."<br>;"
echo "number ". $value[1] ."<br>;"
```

The array indices are wrong and do you notice the semicolon `;` inside the quotes? This should be

```
// correct semicolon use
echo "color ". $value[1] ."<br>";
echo "number ". $value[0] ."<br>";
```

Now let's see a complete function example...

```
function sample_function($arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo "color ". $value[1] ."<br>";
    echo "number ". $value[0] ."<br>";
  }
}

sample_function( test() );
```

But working with arrays like this makes your code difficult to read. You can use the `list` function to create named references to values in the array.

```
function sample_function($arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $value) {
    list($number, $color) = $value;
    echo "color ". $color. "<br>";
    echo "number ". $number ."<br>";
  }
}

sample_function( test() );
```

You can also use string interpolation to improve the readability of the echo. Note, this will only work if you're using double quoted `"` strings, not single quoted `'` strings.

```
function sample_function($arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $value) {
    list($number, $color) = $value;
    echo "color {$color}<br>";
    echo "number {$number}<br>";
  }
}

sample_function( test() );
```

And lastly, you could use an associative array in your original data structure to make it easy to understand your data and easier to use it as well.

```
function test() {
  return array (
    array('number'=>'1', 'color'=>'red'),
    array('number'=>'2', 'color'=>'blue'),
    array('number'=>'3', 'color'=>'green'),
    array('number'=>'4', 'color'=>'yellow')
  );
}

function sample_function($arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
      echo "{$key} {$value}<br>";
    }
  }
}

sample_function( test() );
```

Comment: the line directly above my posted code was "**looking for something along the lines of :** ", which implies that i did not know the correct code to accomplish what i was trying. i'm sorry if my errors offended you, if i knew the correct code i wouldn't be asking the question :) after my code i even asked "**am i going about this incorrectly?**"... so my sample code was bracketed by warnings that it wasn't going to be proper. thanks for your examples of methods to try!

Comment: Oh I didn't take any offence, and I hope none was given either. In general, StackOverflow does not allow questions with syntax errors, but I personally don't mind helping if the asker is polite. I would still recommend that you address all syntax errors first tho, because in doing so, you might end up solving the problem on your own. And it's good to experience the reward of self sufficiency. Best of luck.

Comment: my biggest problem was not finding any examples with a syntax that was at all similar to the limited amount of coding i have already done involving functions and arrays, so i couldn't even muddle through adjusting snippets until they worked for me. so my example was a shot in the dark of how i thought the answer _might_ look. cheers!

Comment: ijason, no problem. I understand this is for wordpress too, and wordpress uses `global` everywhere, but that doesn't mean it is a good idea. Just please try to avoid using `global` in your own code as much as possible. You will thank me later.

Comment: @ijason  you can check my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you want to access and manipulate an array that lives *outside* a function.

Two methods include:

1. Put the array in the global space and call by reference. To do this put an ampersand `&` before the `$` in the function parameter.
2. Use the `global` keyword inside your function.

```php
<?php

$array = array(
            array('1','red'),
            array('2','blue'),
            array('3','green'),
            array('4','yellow')
            );

function output_array($array) {
    $out = '';
    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        $out .= 'number: ' . $arr[0] . ' - color: ' . $arr[1] . '<br />';
    }
    return $out;
}

function modify_array_reference(&$array) {
    $array[0][1] = 'purple';
}

function modify_array_global() {
    global $array;

    $array[0][1] = 'orange';
}

echo output_array($array) . '<br />';
modify_array_reference($array);
echo output_array($array) . '<br />';
modify_array_global();
echo output_array($array) . '<br />';
```

```html
number: 1 - color: red
number: 2 - color: blue
number: 3 - color: green
number: 4 - color: yellow

number: 1 - color: purple
number: 2 - color: blue
number: 3 - color: green
number: 4 - color: yellow

number: 1 - color: orange
number: 2 - color: blue
number: 3 - color: green
number: 4 - color: yellow
```

Comment: recommending `global` for this? are you insane?

Comment: We program in PHP, of course we're insane. Flagellation about good coding practices is all well and good but the questioner deserves to know that the method exists.

Comment: You can program sane PHP. I wish the `global` keyword was renamed to `usingaglobalbecauseineverlearnedhowtoprogram`. That would at least help give people a hint about its real utility.